# Declaring array for use in React Native AutoComplete search engine

Tags: javascript, react-native, object, autocomplete

Not sure where I go about declaring the array with which I want to search from, any assistance would be appreciated. I believe my issue is that I am declaring the "services' array in the incorrect area but I am not sure where else to put it! Or if the commas are the right character to be using in between strings/services

```
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, StatusBar, View, Text, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import AutoComplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';


class CareProviderSequenceScreen extends Component  {

    constructor (props) {
        super (props);
        this.state = {
            services: [],
            query: '',
        }
    }



  render() {
      const query  = this.state;

      const services = {
        "Pick up my Prescription",
        'Pick up groceries',
        'Pick up dry cleaning',
        'Pick up my pet',
    }



      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Autocomplete
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
            //data to show in suggestion
            data={services.length === 1 && comp(query, services[0].title) ? [] : services}
            //default value if you want to set something in input
            defaultValue={query}
            /*onchange of the text changing the state of the query which will trigger
            the findFilm method to show the suggestions*/
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
            placeholder="Enter your need"
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              //you can change the view you want to show in suggestion from here
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: item.title })}>
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                  {item.title} ({item.release_date})
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          />
          <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
            {services.length > 0 ? (
              <Text style={styles.infoText}>{this.state.query}</Text>
            ) : (
              <Text style={styles.infoText}>Enter The Film Title</Text>
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      flex: 1,
      padding: 16,
      marginTop: 40,
    },
    autocompleteContainer: {
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      borderWidth: 0,
    },
    descriptionContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    itemText: {
      fontSize: 15,
      paddingTop: 5,
      paddingBottom: 5,
      margin: 2,
    },
    infoText: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontSize: 16,
    },
  });

export default CareProviderSequenceScreen ;
CareProviderSequenceScreen .navigationOptions = () => ({
    title: "Home & Personal Care",
    headerTintColor: '#9EBBD7',

    headerStyle: {
        height: 65,
        backgroundColor: '#1E5797',
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 1,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.20,
        shadowRadius: 1.41,

        elevation: 2,}
});
```

Comment: You are assigning an object to the services array, everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are assigning an object to services array.

Second, you are not accessing the query state properly. It should be

`const { query } = this.state`